# Avalonia. DataGrid: DataGrid.Styles not calling Converter when editing cell

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

Sample project : [AvaloniaTestColorConverter](https://github.com/davi1td/AvaloniaTestColorConverter/tree/master)

Using Avalonia 11.
Initial load and also adding a new row to the collection works fine. Its supposed to color the Firstname cell green if = "Neil"
However, when editing a Cell, programmatically or in the grid cell it never calls the converter,unless I sort any column. I believe I have notification set properly but who knows ;). Appreciate any help, so confused...

```
// Person Model
public class Person : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _firstName;
    private bool _isFictitious;
    private string _lastName;
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, bool isFictitious)
    {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;

        _isFictitious = isFictitious;
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _firstName;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _firstName, value);
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get => _lastName;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _lastName, value);
    }
    public bool IsFictitious
    {
        get => _isFictitious;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isFictitious, value);
    }
}
```

//ViewModelBase

```
using ReactiveUI;
namespace AvaloniaApplication1.ViewModels;
public class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject
{
}
```

//MainViewModel

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Avalonia.Collections;
using AvaloniaApplication1.Models;
using ReactiveUI;
namespace AvaloniaApplication1.ViewModels;
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private AvaloniaList<Person>? _people;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _people = new AvaloniaList<Person>
        {
            new("Neil", "Armstrong", false),
            new("Buzz", "Lightyear", true),
            new("James", "Kirk", true)
        };
        People = new AvaloniaList<Person>(_people);
        People.CollectionChanged += test;
    }
    public AvaloniaList<Person>? People
    {
        get => _people;
        set
        {
            _people = value;
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _people, value);
        }
    }
    public string Greeting => "Yellow";

    public void ButtonChangeProp()
    {
        if (_people != null) _people[2].FirstName = "Neil";
    }
    public void ButtonAddRow()
    {
        _people?.Add(new Person("Neil", "Armstrong2", false));
    }
    private void test(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

MainView.axaml

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AvaloniaApplication1.ViewModels"
             xmlns:avaloniaApplication1="clr-namespace:AvaloniaApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="AvaloniaApplication1.Views.MainView"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"
             x:CompileBindings="True">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <avaloniaApplication1:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter" />
        <avaloniaApplication1:IsCheckedColorConverter x:Key="IsCheckedColorConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Design.DataContext>
    <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
         to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->

    <vm:MainViewModel />
  </Design.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding ButtonAddRow}" >Add Row</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding ButtonChangeProp}" >Change Prop in Model</Button>
        <DataGrid Height="600" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding People}"        
                  IsReadOnly="False"
                  CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  GridLinesVisibility="All"
                  CellEditEnded="DataGrid_OnCellEditEnded"
                  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"  Binding="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Fictitious?" Binding="{Binding IsFictitious, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.Styles>
                <Style Selector="DataGridCell:nth-child(1)">
                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                            Value="{Binding Converter={ StaticResource ColorConverter} ,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Styles> 
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Greeting}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```